# SQLTransaction or Table Valued Parameters for inserts across multiple tables?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, database, transactions

I have 2 tables, "TableA" for Item Details, "Table B" for File Attachments.

For the insertion of new item details records ( 1 new row in TableA, and possibly multiple rows in TableB in the database), which is a better option:

1) create 2 insert stored procedures (one for each table), and handle the transaction in the application layer
For example:

> try
>
> {
>
> > Connection.Open();
> >
> > SqlTransaction trans transaction= Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);
> >
> > //insert item record here (inserts into TableA in the database)
> >
> > //insert file attachment records here (inserts into TableB in the database)
> >
> > transaction.Commit();
>
> }
>
> catch (Exception Ex)
>
> {
>
> > trans.Rollback();
>
> }

2) create table valued parameter TVPFileAttachments and pass everything into 1 single stored procedure in the database in one operation (transaction handled by stored procedure)

Which is the better standard practice when it comes to updating multiple tables this way?

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 inserts inside transaction.

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO ...
VALUES....
INSERT INTO ....
VALUES....
COMMIT TRAN
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The difficulty i am facing is with updating 1:M table TableB. Please note that to update table b, multiple values have to be passed to the stored procedure, which is why I am asking whether it is the industry practise to use TVP or to use transactions at the application layer

Comment: You can have multiple dml operations at the same time inside one transaction . This code is transactions inside database layer.

Comment: how do u pass in the Table B values then? If there are 10 attachments, do you call the stored procedure 10 times? That is what I am trying to say...

Comment: So you can just use transactions and insert/update. like i edited.